# Can we integrate DOORS tool as a plugin to a java application?

Tags: java, crm, ibm-doors, requirements-management

I would like to integrate the DOORS tool(requirement gathering tool) into my java application.
My application is a standalone application built in java, Can I integrate DOORS tool as a plugin or any other way into my java application.

Answer (score 0):

Domorans project DriveDOORS might be an approach for you. See https://github.com/domoran/DriveDOORS.

Generally, there is no other official way to communicate with DOORS other than starting DXL scripts and getting the results from these scripts, so for every solution you implement you will have to have a DOORS client installed that you communicate with.

Update: I stand corrected: you should be able to use OSLC, see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/oslc-services-rational-doors/index.html

MDconnect by Sodius was a 3rd party tool that helped here, but it seems to be discontinued. But you could ask sodius at https://www.sodiuswillert.com whether they still support it.

Also, with DOORS 9.2 there was a C API that might be usable with java as well, but this also seems to be discontinued, I could not find a later version than this:
http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/rationalsdp/documentation/product_doc/DOORS/version_9-1/doors_api_manual.pdf

Hope this helps
Mike

Comment: Thanks Mike, I will just go through the info you provided ad check the possibilities